Special Character Issue and Data Mismatch in Target CSV File
I’m encountering a problem when loading full data from the source into a target CSV file in SnapLogic. Specifically, I’m seeing special character issues in the target file. When I attempt to address this and reload, a data mismatch issue arises.
I’ve tried debugging each Snap multiple times, and I’m using the Mapper Snap to load data column-wise correctly, but I still can’t identify the root cause of these issues.
Has anyone experienced similar issues or have insights on how to resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Tried to use escape character in csv file, wrote expression in mapper snap to avoid special character Issue.

Can we please get a [mcve]?
